# Continuous dependent variable that almost looks like a categorical variable

Tags: categorical-data, continuous-data

I recently conducted an experiment where people had to decide how much money to take from another participant. People could choose to pick any value between 0 and 100 percent. It turns out that around 40% of the participants decided to take nothing, 40% to take everything, and only 20% took a positive amount different from 100. So, in effect, the data that I get looks categorical although it is continuous, (given that people could have chosen any amount between 0 and 100).

I was wondering what kind of regressions I could carry out in this situation? The residuals in an OLS regression are highly non-normal, so I don't think that an OLS regression would be a good idea. Moreover, I'm not sure it makes sense to carry out logit regressions, given that the variable is not really categorical.

Comment: Are those 20% all lumped around taking 50%? Or are they spread out from 1% to 99%?

Comment: They are spread out mainly from 1% to 50%, with a small peak at 50% (representing 7% of the observations). There are few observations above 50% that are different from 100%

Comment: How many observations and how many potential predictors do you got?

Comment: I have 193 observations, and various demographic variables (around 10 of them)

Comment: Clear case for ordinal regression.